# header is not working to my manage page when my users with privlieges log in

Tags: php, html, css

Here is my code for my index.php page. My header is not working as in not redirecting me to the manage.php page when my users with privs accesses it. The header in my manage.php doesn't work either. I would gladly appreciate anyone's help. I tried re-typing the whole thing again, pasting my instructors code too just to see if maybe it was me that made a mistake but still didn't work, I tried everything :(

```
<?php
require_once("../req_globals.php");
$error = false;
$message = '';
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // echo $username;
    if(empty($username))
    { 
        $error = true;
        $message = $message . "<p>You forgot your username.</p>";
    }

    if (empty($password)) 
    {
        $error = true;
        $message = $message . "<p>Do you even password bro?</p>";
    }
    if($error == false)
    {
        // echo "working";
        $user = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users 
                        WHERE username = '" . $username . "' 
                        AND password = '" . $password . "' 
                        LIMIT 1");

        $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($user);
        $userWorker = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user);

        if($userCount < 1) 
        {
            $error = true;
            $message = $message . "<p>You don't exist...</p>";
            echo $userCount;
        }
        else 
        {
            if ($userWorker["privs"] == "No") 
            {
                $error = true;
                $message = $message . "<p>YOU SHALL NOT PASS!!!</p>";
            }
            if ($error == false) 
            {
                session_start();

                $_SESSION['firstname'] = $userWorker['firstname'];
                $_SESSION['privs'] = $userWorker['privs'];

                header('Location:ad_manage.php?login=success');
            }
        }
    }


}

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ??

Comment: See also: https://xkcd.com/327/. Avoid directly using the username and password to build the query string. It's a great way to receive a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

Are you outputting anything before the header is declared? If so, it is not going to work as the headers were already sent.
If no, then try this:

```
$root = getenv('HTTP_HOST');
header("Location: http://$root/ad_manage.php?login=success");
exit();
```

Comment: I fixed it! It was that my form was redirecting to my index.php rather than my manage.php which is weird but it ended up working after all. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @BrigittVillatoro Glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location:ad_manage.php?login=success');
exit();
```